# How to use codec in JMF

Tags: java, jmf

I want play compressed audio files. I want to know how to specify the codec(Ex. G711,G729 etc..) in the player of JMF. Any source,link if available,let me know.

I referred [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip24.html). but no Codec  has been used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have JMF installed in your PC you can use the JMF Customizer to specify the codecs. All types of codecs are not installed with the JMF. You have to add them.

For more look [here](http://www.stierlen2.homepage.t-online.de/modellbau/3dscanner/jmf_installation.htm)